# How to fix git network issue on Ubuntu in Hyper-V?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtual-machine, git, hyper-v

I've installed Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 on Hyper-V in Windows 10 Pro (Version 1809).
And I setup the network using Default Switch.
The git is the default one installed on the system with version 2.17.1

The system can access the internet, however, when I'm trying to clone a large-size git repository (For instance, [git](https://github.com/git/git) on github), I've received this error:

> error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-12): A TLS fatal alert has been received.
>
> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Even when using ssh, the error still occurred:

> Connection to github.com closed by remote host.
>
> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Then I tried to mirror the project on gitlab and then clone it, the error also occurred, which means that the problem isn't due to the remote side.

When I tried to clone it from WSL, there is no error.

However, when I'm trying to clone a small-size repository, there is no error.

Changing postBuffer doesn't help.

One possible solution is to use the External Switch (the error fixed), however, this make the network on both the host and the virtual machine really slow, so that's impossible to use that.

Comment: Using an external switch should not affect network performance.  Make sure you've updated your drivers for your network card.  If possible, use a wired NIC instead of a wireless.

Answer (score -1):

This problem troubled me for the last 5 months.
I just bought me a new laptop with Windows 10 because of Hyper-V usage on my latest freelance Golang job.
I could work around the problem by using an External Switch but Internet became very slow.
Last week (after I finished the Golang job) I had some more time to dive into it and finally I could fix it.
The following solution will definitely help:

The latest version of Windows Hyper-V has problems with your Wi-Fi driver. You should get the latest version from https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/28876/Windows-10-Wi-Fi-Drivers-for-Intel-Wireless-Adapters?v=t

Here is the problem: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4253

Regards,
Ton

Comment: What does an issue with WSL have to do with Hyper-V?  I very much doubt the author was using 1909 in May.